# Configure domain DNS to connect to Azure website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to configure the DNS of a domain to connect to an Azure website.

I added the following DNS records to my registrar control panel:

```
Type            Host       Value
A Record        @          IP given in Azure Website 
CNAME Record    wwww       mysite.azurewebsites.net
TXT Record      @          mysite.azurewebsites.net
```

But when I try to access the site using www.mysite.com it does not resolve.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
When I try to validate the domain I get and error on Domain Ownership.
But the true is that the CNAME exists on my DNS ... 
Any idea what might be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding DNS records to your registrar control panel, you also need to add your host name in Azure portal to enable the custom domain name for your app. Steps below are for your reference.

1. In the Azure portal, click App Services on the left menu.
2. Click your app, then click Custom domains > Add hostname.
3. Add the FQDN of your custom domain to the list (e.g. www.contoso.com).

[image]

4. Click Validate.
5. Upon clicking Validate Azure will kick off Domain Verification workflow. This will check for Domain ownership as well as Hostname availability and report success or detailed error with prescriptive guidence on how to fix the error.
6. Upon successful validation Add hostname button will become active and you will be able to the assign hostname.
7. Once Azure finishes configuring your new custom domain name, navigate to your custom domain name in a browser. The browser should open your Azure app, which means that your custom domain name is configured properly.

For more information, link below is for your reference.

[Map a custom domain name to an Azure app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name)

Comment: The reason for this by the way is that IP addresses are shared in Azure. So even if you hit the right IP address, the Host header sent by the browser tells Azure what site you are trying to access. That allows them to find the app that defines that domain name. If you don't define it in the Web App, the request can't be routed.

Comment: @Amor - MSFT I tried what you wrote before with no success. I just updated my question. Am I missing something?

Comment: After CNAME record created, It will take some time for the DNS changes to propagate. To check whether your DNS configuration is usable, you could open http://digwebinterface.com/ and input your host name(www.something.com) in the "Hostnames or IP addresses" textbox and click Dig button.

Comment: Tha problem was with my registrar which was not updating the DNS records.Just marked the answer.